# Entity Framework many to many relationship Load children

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6, code-first

I am using EF 6 Code-first to create my database.
I have two entities Expenses and Tags that have many to many to relationship.

```
public class Expense : Entity
{

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    //public long TagId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public long ByUserId { get; set; }
    public User ByUser { get; set; }

    public long? ForUserId { get; set; }
    public User ForUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
}
```

and Tag Class is

```
 public class Tag : Entity
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Expense.Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured entities using EntityTypeConfiguration like

```
internal class ExpenseConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Expense>
{
    public ExpenseConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasRequired(x => x.ByUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ByUserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasOptional(x => x.ForUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ForUserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasMany(x => x.Tags)
            .WithMany(t => t.Expenses)
            .Map(et => { 
                et.MapLeftKey("ExpenseId");
                et.MapRightKey("TagId");
                et.ToTable("tblExpenseTags");
            });
    }
}

internal class TagConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Tag>
{
    public TagConfiguration()
    {

    }
}
```

everything goes well. It creates database tables properly with a new table "tblExpenseTags" which contains many to many relationship of Expense and Tag.

The problem is while loading.

if I use

```
database.Entry(expense).Collection("Tags").Load();
```

it works i.e. it loads Tags,  where database is DbContext.

but when I use

```
dbSet.Where(x=>x.Id == 8).Include(x=>x.Tags);
```

it does not work. My assumption is if .Load() works then .Include  should also work ?

am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `Include` before the filter predicate:

```
var expensesWithTags = dbSet.Include(x => x.Tags).Where(x => x.Id == 8);
```

...but since you are querying against the expense `Id`, you probably want to use a `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` predicate instead:

```
var expenseWithTags = dbSet.Include(x => x.Tags)
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 8);
```